# dash.exceptions.DependencyException thrown after increasing the number of processes in Dash application

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, gunicorn

I have a Dash 2.7 application that used to run with 5 threads and 1 (gunicorn) process. To introduce true parallelisation I have increased the number of processes to 7, but since then from time to time I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 914, in serve_component_suites
    _validate.validate_js_path(self.registered_paths, package_name, path_in_pkg)
  File "/Users/dade/.conda/envs/viz-davide/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 357, in validate_js_path
    raise exceptions.DependencyException(
dash.exceptions.DependencyException: Error loading dependency. "dash_tabulator" is not a registered library.
Registered libraries are:
[]
```

This error appears in the logs 7 times, so it looks like each process tried to do the same thing and failed.

The application uses a Flask filesystem cache which, from what I read, is thread safe. The application does also have some functions that are annotated with `@lru_cache` and I wonder whether this could be the source of the problem. If this is the issue, what is the best way to make the LRU cached functions thread safe?

My attempt:

```
def foo():
    return _cached_foo(process_id=os.getpid(), thread_id=threading.get_native_id())


@lru_cache
def _cached_foo(process_id: int, thread_id: int):
    return something_not_thread_safe()
```